I'm writing my first book but I don't know how to go from chapter to chapter
Is it normal to start and have an idea of what I want to write about but not know how to go from chapter to chapter or to just kind of not know where I'm going with it?

Welcome to Writing.SE! Are you asking for help with how you could resolve this?

Yes.  It's even possible to write when you have no idea what to write about!

Yes, this is called "Discovery Writing", a famous practitioner of this is Stephen King. He wrote a book on it, Titled "On Writing", which  is well worth buying.
I am also a Discovery Writer. It is also known as "seat of the pants" writing, but I find that pejorative. The alternative is "plotters", writers that have outlined every detail of the entire plot from the beginning, have devised all their characters in detail with personality and a history, have built their world (where the story takes place) with details, and when it comes to writing, they just workman-like write to the plan from start to end.
I discovered decades ago that I cannot do that. Once I know how it all turns out; I get bored with the task of writing.
A Discovery writer, by contrast, is very character oriented. I imagine people, generally a likeable character as the hero. I give them some talent (or super power), and I give them some critical flaw that will have a large impact on their success, and I imagine a situation, a problem that they feel they must address, or must solve.
Then I start writing. The last book I wrote, I was doing my morning walk with the dogs just imagining my character and their personality for over a month before I wrote a word. I knew her inside out, I knew why she was as she was, the traumas and bits of life story that made her that way. No other major characters, just her, and I found a problem she would feel compelled to solve that relied almost entirely on her weakness, the one thing she couldn't fight her way out of, or con her way out of.
The reason I do that is because overcoming her weakness (finally, after it has kicked her ass multiple times) is the heroic growth readers want to see.
Discovery writing is letting the characters you build up in your mind do what they would do in each situation. We don't force them to make mistakes, they always, heroes, villains, sidekicks and extras, do their best at every turn.
There should be no reader "groaners", characters making mistakes just for the sake of forcing the plot in some direction. As King says, every story is going to turn out somehow.
The only thing you need to "force" is that the hero(es) and villain(s) cannot stand still. No giving up, no bowing out. They must move, advance or retreat to regroup, but neither can give up the fight until the final confrontation that resolves the story. Even if all the hero's allies are dead or fled, if they must stand against an army alone, they will.
To me, this is the hallmark of a fictional hero, they would rather die than fail.
Discovery writers let the character's decisions drive the plot.
If you don't like where the plot is going, go back to the "past" (earlier writing) and see what else you could have done.
I would suggest you steal one thing from the plotters; as a guide to your writing: The Three Act Structure (3AS).
This is the most popular (and best-selling) story structure for novels and movies.
However, historically, the 3AS was developed by looking at existing stories that people found compelling, and finding that many followed the same basic structure.
(Campbell's Hero's Journey is similar but more detailed; he analyzed thousands of myths, many several centuries old, and distilled a common structure amongst them -- Most have many elements of that structure, but not always all of them.)
The purpose for studying the 3AS is to use it as a guide. Stories following the 3AS can be broken down into 8 (or even 16) equally lengthy parts. The first Act, for example, introduces our hero in their Normal World; so we can get to see their personality there. At the midpoint of Act I, we have something called the Inciting Incident, whatever happens to the Hero that introduces a problem they cannot ignore, they feel compelled to solve.
In the second half of Act I, the hero has tried to solve the problem, but it has gotten worse, and in fact by the end of Act I the hero is forced (either physically or metaphorically) to leave their Normal World and devote all their time to solving The Problem.
Note, of course, the Problem may be an active villain, or the "villain" could be nature, or impending death, or their mother has cancer, or a new competitor in their business, whatever.
The reason for Discovery writers to be aware of this is that ultimately, to be saleable, the easiest thing to sell are stories in the 3AS, everybody that buys stories gets it and likes it and knows they aren't taking a huge chance on it, if the writing is good.
As a Discovery writer, I use the 3AS more like a compass: Depending on where I am in the story, I know the type of writing I should be doing.
I am writing Normal world stuff, and heading for the Inciting Incident.
Then I am writing complications, heading toward leaving the Normal World.
Then I am writing Act IIA, adding complexity, raising the stakes, and leading to my hero's first failure.
And so on, through the 8 equal parts I like to use. I am not defining ahead of time what those turning points are, I'll figure that out when I get there.
And, truth be told, Discovery writing involves a lot more rewriting, we hit road blocks and do not want to do something unrealistic, so we have to go back in the past and engineer our way around hitting the road block.
Stephen King did that in The Stand, hit a road block in the plot, and unable to think of a way around it, finally scrapped about a hundred pages of writing and starting over from that point, with an incident that killed a dozen characters.
Get used to rewrites!
But at least for me, Discovery writing keeps me entertained throughout the writing, and I never feel like my characters are acting out of character, everything they say and do is entirely consistent with their personality, for better or worse. They never do anything a reader would think is out of character; in fact they know the character so well they may anticipate them -- "Jack, don't hit him, for god's sake... Dammit Jack!"
That's what you want, your readers finding your characters so realistic, they feel like real people they know.
To be simplistic, for Plotters, the plot drives the characters. For Discovery writers, the characters drive the plot.
You don't have to "know where you're going with it." Make sure your characters keep moving, and it will come out somewhere. Study and use the 3AS as a compass to point in the direction you should be writing.
You should know how to go from Chapter to Chapter, the 3AS will help with that, but in general the Chapter ends at a turning point; a point of change or transition. Something is decided, the hero (or villain) has set something in motion, or has done something, and now some time passes while that takes effect, and the next chapter begins with that passage of time not shown.
Or, if you write both from the hero's POV and the villain's POV, same idea -- the hero begins her trek to Shanghai, and while she is doing that boring task, let's see what the villain has been doing all this time...

No, absolutely not… but that doesn't matter.
The most basic advice you might have got in primary school is that every story has a beginning, a middle, and an end.
Although that's largely irrelevant, it's literally true and for writers stuck in your situation, it does provide a way out.
Does your story basically have a beginning, a middle, and an end or does it need deeper analysis?
If it did have a beginning, a middle, and an end could you define those sections in your own way, and use those to provide at least three chapters?

Is it normal? Yes.
I use to just sit and write (when I could get myself in the mood). But I had poor organization skills. I used temporary lists, index cards, and even diagrams while working out a story, but relied on memory and 'feelings' when I sat down to write.
My work suffered in predictable ways: circular structure, no pacing, not being sure where in the character's arc I was at any scene, and character drifts that undermined my story goals. I had a good 'tone', but in retrospect tone was all I had – and wasted on a 1st draft anyway.
I couldn't force myself to write because I didn't know the (daily) goal, and I couldn't judge when I'd reached the goal in what I did write. At worst, I repeated situations with the same emotional beats, sometimes by different characters in the same story, reaching the same conclusions.
As I got older and developed better organizational skills, my writing got better.
I would go a step further and admit that the writing software Scrivener made it possible to retrieve my story notes and creatively write in the same interface. Having one place to put all my notes means any brainstorm (no matter how small) can be added to the document in roughly the position where it needs to go. I can massage it on my next pass through that section of the story.
Mythos of spontaneous prose vs 'static' plotting
There is a hyperbolic misconception that if you do ANY plotting in advance it can never be changed. I have no idea why that would ever be a thing. Of course my story notes get updated as I write. It is a digital document. It is only as settled as I want it to be.
I have been told that 'plotting kills their creativity' by people here who say they don't do it. I find the opposite to be true. I find it easier to create, and am more confident with my decisions. My structured writing has much more intent and emotional impact when I read it later. I am more proud of my work that is deliberate. It is better writing.
But it's a strong mythos.
Jack Kerouac's On the Road was claimed to have been 'pantsed' in one long amphetamine binge on a single roll of paper. The meta-idea of a single-writing jamsession played into the style of the story. In reality there were six drafts, and it was edited for many years before publication. Kerouac lied, hid earlier drafts, and blamed a dog for eating the original ending to protect this unhelpful mythology.
Agatha Christie famously said she doesn't know who the murderer is while she's writing, but she left behind notebooks full of 'plotting' that indicate the exact opposite. She worked and re-worked her stories with outlines, details, and character notes as she went. Her psychological puzzles would not hold up 100 years later if she was just winging it on feelings until the last page. Some stories could work that way, not hers.
I'm not sure we're all using the same definitions. Even Amadeus's answer states they planned for a month before writing – I would just call that 'plotting'? I do not understand the distinction, but I respect we have different meanings for the word.
The label is not important to me. I was a poorly organized 'plotter' before, and relied on tone to carry my writing (and missed more than I hit). I'm now a more organized 'plotter' because I've learned to use a modern writing tool (and some maturity in knowing what I want to say). It is not some philosophy I would split all writers into. The reality seems like everyone plans and everyone writes spontaneously, but you need both however it's labeled.
Labels to action
I think you are 'plotting' simply by having a story idea ahead of time, but you're not plotting enough where it helps you when you physically sit to write.
A minimal outline is (imo) mandatory for a writing that lasts more than a few pages. Make a short priority list when you sit down to write. Refresh your story goals, how far along the characters are, and what storybeats need to happen. Put that list in some story-order and it becomes a plot outline. Even if you do not write it as prose, you worked on your story in a very practical way. It is progress.
Next time you sit down in the mood, you know what to write.
You should have a loose master plan for the whole story, and more beat-for-beat plans for individual chapters (or however the story is organized). But maybe the real trick is to learn how to set goals and work towards them even when not in the mood to write prose.
Ultimately it's up to you how to reach your goals. It sounds like your current method might be helped with a little more organized planning, but like any writing technique it's a skill that comes with practice.

If you have an idea but don't know where to go with it, you have two options:

Discovery-write
Just start writing the part that you have and let the story guide you as you discover what comes next. As you write, the story will slowly unfold, until you reach its natural end.

Brainstorm
Just take what you have and allow your mind to come up with related ideas. You can do this systematically using established brainstorming techniques. Or you can daydream or take long walks and just let your mind drift. And you can help your mind by looking up the ideas that you have on the internet and see what kind of news or images or other information comes up.
You may need to carry your idea around for a while until a story grows from it in your mind.


